# base64_decode truncates array causes unserialize to return false

Tags: php, serialization, base64, decode

I am logging user actions on an online application. So, I have a rather large (but not that large) multidimentional array that I am storing into database.
To do so, I am using base64 encode / decode and serialize / unserialize.

Here is the method I use to serialize my array:

```
$this->detail = base64_encode(serialize($detailedInfo));
```

And here how I'm getting back the data:

```
$logDetail = unserialize(base64_decode($log->detail));
```

It happens that sometimes, unserialize returns false.

I've debugged a little and it seams that when the array gets larger, base64 encode or decode truncates the data.
Here's a dump of the result of base64_decode on a smaller array:

```
a:2:{s:8:"products";a:7:{i:15;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:2:"15";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"110224";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"15,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"17";s:9:"hoppValue";d:17;}i:837;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:3:"837";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"322713";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"15,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"17";s:9:"hoppValue";d:17;}i:2405;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2405";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"849755";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"15,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"17";s:9:"hoppValue";d:17;}i:2433;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2433";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"855839";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"15,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"17";s:9:"hoppValue";d:17;}i:2494;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2494";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"921545";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"15,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"17";s:9:"hoppValue";d:17;}i:2625;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2625";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"971694";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"15,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"17";s:9:"hoppValue";d:17;}i:2626;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2626";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"971769";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"15,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"17";s:9:"hoppValue";d:17;}}s:5:"dates";a:3:{s:4:"post";a:2:{s:7:"dtStart";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"06/06/2016";}s:5:"dtEnd";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"08/08/2016";}}s:4:"hopp";a:2:{s:7:"dtStart";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"2016-06-06";}s:5:"dtEnd";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"2016-08-08";}}s:5:"weeks";a:11:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-06-06";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-06-12";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-06-13";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-06-19";}i:2;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-06-20";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-06-26";}i:3;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-06-27";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-06-30";}i:4;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-07-01";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-07-03";}i:5;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-07-04";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-07-10";}i:6;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-07-11";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-07-17";}i:7;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-07-18";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-07-24";}i:8;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-07-25";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-07-31";}i:9;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-08-01";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-08-07";}i:10;a:2:{s:5:"first";s:10:"2016-08-08";s:4:"last";s:10:"2016-08-14";}}}}
```

Here unserialize works fine!

When the array is larger it seams truncated (just end of string line due to body char number limit):

```
(...) a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2237";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"712854";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2267;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2267";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"712954";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2285;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2285";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"712975";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2287;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2287";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"712979";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2312;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2312";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"753212";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2317;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2317";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"754455";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2324;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2324";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"757439";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2336;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2336";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"759302";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2338;a:4:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2338";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"759302";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";}i:2343;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2343";s:3:"zuc";s:6:"765495";s:8:"oldValue";s:6:"12,000";s:5:"value";s:2:"15";s:9:"hoppValue";d:15;}i:2351;a:5:{s:9:"idProduct";s:4:"2351";s:3:"zuc";s:6:
```

And then, unserialize returns false.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a limit on the size of the array to be encoded / decoded (didn't find any info anywhere)

Here's an example of the logDetail array (a small example, that works):

```
    Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [idProduct] => 15
                    [zuc] => 110224
                    [oldValue] => 17,000
                    [value] => 20
                    [hoppValue] => 20
                )

            [837] => Array
                (
                    [idProduct] => 837
                    [zuc] => 322713
                    [oldValue] => 17,000
                    [value] => 20
                    [hoppValue] => 20
                )

            [2405] => Array
                (
                    [idProduct] => 2405
                    [zuc] => 849755
                    [oldValue] => 17,000
                    [value] => 20
                    [hoppValue] => 20
                )

            [2433] => Array
                (
                    [idProduct] => 2433
                    [zuc] => 855839
                    [oldValue] => 17,000
                    [value] => 20
                    [hoppValue] => 20
                )

            [2494] => Array
                (
                    [idProduct] => 2494
                    [zuc] => 921545
                    [oldValue] => 17,000
                    [value] => 20
                    [hoppValue] => 20
                )

            [2625] => Array
                (
                    [idProduct] => 2625
                    [zuc] => 971694
                    [oldValue] => 17,000
                    [value] => 20
                    [hoppValue] => 20
                )

            [2626] => Array
                (
                    [idProduct] => 2626
                    [zuc] => 971769
                    [oldValue] => 17,000
                    [value] => 20
                    [hoppValue] => 20
                )

        )

    [dates] => Array
        (
            [post] => Array
                (
                    [dtStart] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 06/06/2016
                        )

                    [dtEnd] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 08/08/2016
                        )

                )

            [hopp] => Array
                (
                    [dtStart] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-06-06
                        )

                    [dtEnd] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-08-08
                        )

                )

            [weeks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-06-06
                            [last] => 2016-06-12
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-06-13
                            [last] => 2016-06-19
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-06-20
                            [last] => 2016-06-26
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-06-27
                            [last] => 2016-06-30
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-07-01
                            [last] => 2016-07-03
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-07-04
                            [last] => 2016-07-10
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-07-11
                            [last] => 2016-07-17
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-07-18
                            [last] => 2016-07-24
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-07-25
                            [last] => 2016-07-31
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-08-01
                            [last] => 2016-08-07
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [first] => 2016-08-08
                            [last] => 2016-08-14
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This article may be of help https://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues

Comment: can you provide an example of the data in `$detailedInfo` ?

Comment: In the example above, I have only 7 products. The examples that causes base64_decode (or maybe the encode) to truncate the string is when I have a lot more (200 or so) products...

Comment: Just a thought... We're kind of obsessed with base64-encoding everything nowadays. Are you sure you need that extra step? Most databases offer column types for binary data. As about the code you've shared, there's no way to know which function is failing. Have you clearly determined it's `unserialize()` and not `base64_decode()`?

Comment: What happens in between? Are you storing the data somewhere or transporting the data through something that may truncate it?

Comment: I store it in database in a blob field (I tried to change the field to TEXT, and the same happens)

Comment: Can you confirm that the base 64 text is not being truncated?

Comment: I've tried to base64_encode(serialize()); and then unserialize(base64_decode()); without storing data into database, and it work. 
I guess then, it is the database that is truncating my field. 
As @ÁlvaroGonzález sugested, I removed the extra base64_encode (since it seams to take 33% more space) and inserting and extracting data from the database works fine.

Comment: It guess it was my BLOB field that was truncating my serialized array. I tried with even bigger log action and had the same error.
I've changed the field from BLOB to LONGBLOB and now it seams to work

Answer (score 0):

Looks serious I didn't get that problem

Basicly I reproduce your data and put it into your idea of serialize and base64
I made this code and it works...

```
<?php 

$products = [];
$dates = ['post' =>
            ['dtStart' =>
                [0 => '06/06/2016'], 
            'dtEnd' => 
                [0 => '08/08/2016']
            ]
            ,'hopp' => 
            ['dtStart' =>
                [0 => '2016-06-06'], 
            'dtEnd' => 
                [0 => '2016-08-08']
            ]
        ];

for($i = 0, $l = 11; $i < $l; $i++){
    $dates['weeks'][] = ['first' => '2016-06-06', 'last' => '2016-06-12'];
}

for($j = 0, $m = 7; $j < $m; $j++){
    $products[$j] = [
        'idProduct' => $j,
        'zuc' => random_int ( 100000 , 999999 ),
        'oldValue' => random_int ( 1 , 50 ),
        'value' => random_int ( 1 , 50 ),
        'hoppValue' => random_int ( 1 , 50 )
    ];
} 

$data = ['products' => $products, 'dates' => $dates];

ob_start();
var_dump($data);
$firstResult = ob_end_clean();

$rawData = base64_encode(serialize($data));

ob_start();
var_dump(unserialize(base64_decode($rawData)));
$secondResult = ob_end_clean();

var_dump(strcmp($firstResult, $secondResult));
```

result is `int(0)` [**PHP.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) says: `Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.` that means there is no differ. I think your out is trimed or the database trims the data, try to figure that out.